# What Excel formula can find the last X characters of a cell up to Y character?

Tags: excel-formula

I need to fill a cell with the characters of another cell up to a point. For example, cell A1 includes a URL like `http://mysite.com/product.asp?ic=ipod123`. I need a formula that will start from the end of the string and copy all of the characters until it gets to the `=` sign.

So when A1 includes `http://mysite.com/product.asp?ic=ipod123`, then A2 will become `ipod123`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your string URL is in A1, the to get the arg you can use:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) - FIND("=",A1))
```

Comment: Worked out great! One minor issue is that if the cell that should have the URL is empty, the formula returns `#VALUE!`. Is there anyway to make it return a blank cell instead of an error?

Comment: Wrap it in an `IF` that tests for the empty cell: `=IF(A1<>"",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) - FIND("=",A1)),"")`. This is why excel formulae get really horrible - you just keep on wrapping them up.

Answer (score 0):

On my Excel, I had to change the coma by semi-colons:

```
=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1) - FIND("=";A1))
```

Comment: This would be related to the either the version of Excel you have, or the locale (ie language). ; is sometimes used where , is the numeric decimal place separator. See http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091103154938AABd3ie

Answer (score 0):

To get last part of string by last character like in MySQL Substring index

```
 mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', 2);
    -> 'www.mysql'

 mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', -1);
    -> 'com'
```

In Excel you can use:

```
=RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2) - FIND("^^",SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","^^",LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","")))))
```

to find last position of character (Ex." " in a cell )

```
=FIND("^^",SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","^^",LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ",""))))
```